# SQL Server : expensive queries in case statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that looks like this

```
UPDATE users u 
SET bestFriend = calculateBestFriend(u.birthday, u.hometown, u.pet) 
WHERE u.id = 7
```

The problem is, `calculateBestFriend` will return NULL if no friends are found and -1 if multiple best friends are found.  However, for the users, NULL is what is wanted in either case.  I can't modify `calculateBestFriend`.

I want to do something like this

```
UPDATE users u 
SET bestFriend = 
    CASE calculateBestFriend(u.birthday, u.hometown, u.pet) 
       WHEN -1 THEN NULL
       ELSE whateverCameBack
WHERE u.id = 7
```

I wouldn't want to do this

```
UPDATE users u 
SET bestFriend = 
   CASE 
      WHEN calculateBestFriend(u.birthday, u.hometown, u.pet) = -1 THEN NULL
      ELSE calculateBestFriend(u.birthday, u.hometown, u.pet) 
WHERE u.id = 7
```

because `calculateBestFriend` is expensive.

Comment: Could you add it to from part using cross apply and then use case on that?

Comment: Why are you not able to edit "calculateBestFriend"? Is it a function? Maybe you can wrap this function with something like this:
calculateBestFriend(p_birthday, p_hometown, p_pet, p_defaultReturnValueIfNoFriend)

Comment: @etalon11 Mostly organization issues.  Our project doesn't own "calculateBestFriend", another project does.  On top of that, they actually do want the distinction for some of their logic.  I could wrap the function but that feels like overkill for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the record from `calculateBestFriend()` and store it into a `cte`, and then update said `cte`.  The update to the `cte` will be cascaded to the source table.

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, calculateBestFriend(u.birthday, u.hometown, u.pet) as calculatedBestFriend
  FROM users u
  WHERE u.id = 7
)
UPDATE cte 
SET cte.bestFriend = 
    CASE 
       WHEN cte.calculatedBestFriend = -1 THEN NULL
       ELSE cte.calculatedBestFriend
    END
```

Comment: This is the right thing but I'll have to work it in.  The proc I'm working on has several statements doing roughly the same thing (Think something like `userParents`, `userDogs`, `userFish`)

Answer (score 0):

One obvious way would be the change your calculateBestFriend() function to return exactly what you want (or create a new one). However, generally I would avoid the use of functions in queries and you will find that often you can achieve the same thing without them. Have a closer look at your schema and see if this is possible.